# Batch change link "Start In" directory

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, batch-rename

I have some 100~ish links in a directory. I want t change all of their 'start in' to "", i.e. nothing. It is very tedious to do this one by one in properties.

Is there any easy way (without recreating each of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lnkedit is a nice tool that allows helps you to do this. It can be found here: http://iain.cx/src/lnkedit/

Once you have it you can use it in a script to do batch operations. Just use the: `-d` flag to change the "starts in".

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows I use Bulk Renamer to do things like this.

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php

It's great for stripping the start or end of filenames. It even has regex capabilities and the GUI allows drag and drop. I keep it in my library of programs that can be copied to new machines without needing to be installed.

Comment: Not sure you got what OP was asking... I think it's the "start in" directory property, not the start of the name of the file.

Comment: I see, I think the batch-rename tag on the question is what mislead me. The screenshots from the website are a newer version than I have and includes altering file properties, but that doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: yeah I checked the site and it didn't seem to do this property. It's mostly for renaming.